# Is it possible to apply an FMJ or Extended Mag variant in the Zombies gamemode?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I play zombies a lot, and have at least the Extended Mag variant for the 48 Dredge. I know I am able to apply variants for the attachments in Weapon Kits, but what about FMJ and Extended Mag? I could have sworn I watched a video of someone who had the variant of the Extended Mag or FMJ attachment on their gun.